# Detect touch of UIImage added as subview of UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uitouch

I have `UIScrollView` with many `UIImageViews`.I need to drag and drop image from `UIScrollView` to another view. Outside the scrollView touch is worked. But inside scroll view touch is not worked. I used `touchesBegan`,`touchesMoved` etc method. Please help me.

```
-(IBAction)selectBut:(id)sender
{

 scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)];

 scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

 int y = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i++) {

UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y, 75, 30)];

 image.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

  y=y+35;

 [scrollView addSubview:image];

}

[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(150, 300)]

}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

{

   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch tapCount] == 1) {

        NSLog(@"One touch !!");
    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried setting the UIImageView to `[self setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE]`? its disabled by default if im not mistaken.

Comment: @IkmalEzzani, UserInteractionEnabled is true.but it is not working.

Comment: Inside UIScrollView touchesBegan is not work for subviews. Just verify my answer.

Comment: @Madhu ,pls give some line of sample code

Comment: check it updated my answer with sample code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to customize the `UIImageView` with your own view **inherited** from `UIImageView`. Provide touch methods in that customized subclass and add it on your `UIScrollView`..

Subviews of `UIScrollview` will never call `touchesBegan` method directly. You need to customized with subview to get `touchesBegan` properties of that added subview/customized view.

I mean to say take subclass of ImageView like

```
CustomImageView *imageView = [[CustomImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
[imageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
```

`CustomImageView` class is should be inherited from UIImageView like

```
 @interface CustomImageView : UIImageView
  {
  }
```

in # .m File

```
  #import "CustomImageView.h"

@implementation CustomImageView


    - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
   {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {

}
return self;
}



    - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
      NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

     }

    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {


    }

    - (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {


    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

      if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
    drawImageView.image = nil;
    return;
    }

     }
```

Comment: @madhu : I appreciate your answer. Really great and helpful!!

Answer (score 3):

Add a Tap gesture recognizer to the scroll view for enabling touch inside scroll view:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singlTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(methodName:)];
singlTap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO; //Default value for cancelsTouchesInView is YES, which will prevent buttons to be clicked
[scrollViewName addGestureRecognizer:singlTap];
```

then write your code in specified method.

```
-(void)methodName:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
     //your code here
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to set exclusiveTouch to yes like Bhargavi mentioned below... If you don't do this than the user might accidentally "tap" the image when they are just scrolling... `exclusiveTouch` will prevent accidental touches that way if the user is just scrolling through (especially with Paging enabled) they won't accidentally trigger 50 gagillion (real number) taps.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this help you. But try to set the `exclusiveTouch` property of the `UIImageView` to `YES`.

Comment: This is important! Many leave this out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your scrollview as an IBOutlet? If its from xib and as you say touches are available outside the scroll and not within, I guess you might have accidentally unchecked **userInteractionEnabled** for the scrollview which inhibits touch events. And you have added UIImageViews as subviews to UIScrollView. For UIImageView you have to first set **userInteractionEnabled** to **YES** and then add any gestures if necessary to get events or use the **touchesBegan, touchesMoved** methods. Unless you set interaction enabled you wont receive touch events on UIImageView. If the parent view I mean the UIScrollView's interaction is disabled you wont get touches on UIImageView too. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I added UIScrollView programatically.I set  scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES . But touch not working..

Comment: ya,touch on image is not working.UIScrollView contains all images.

Comment: Are you able to scroll the view on touch?? Does the scrollview detects  touch? How did you add touch receptors on UIImageview? Did you set userinteractionEnabled YES for UIImageview?

Comment: I think your scrollView delegates overrides touch methods. Moreover touch on UIImageview is a headache as they dont work well as we expect. Try adding a UIButton of type custom over the image with frame as that of your imageviews. Or can you just add a tap gesture over imageView and check whether its working??